Without assuming Kähler, does $d$-exactness still imply $\bar\partial$-exactness?
For a complex manifold $M$ with differential $d$ and Dolbeault operators $\partial,\bar\partial$, it is clear that $$d\alpha = \partial\alpha + \bar\partial\alpha$$ implies $\partial\alpha=\bar\partial\alpha=0$ for any $\alpha\in A^{p,q}(M)$, since $\partial\alpha\in A^{p+1,q}(M)$ and $\bar\partial\alpha\in A^{p,q+1}(M)$. In other words, $[\alpha]\in H_{\text{deRham}}^{p+q}(M)$.
If one could show that $d$-exactness of $\alpha$ also implies $\bar\partial$-exactness, this would mean that one could see the deRham-cohomology groups as a sub-groups of the Dolbeault cohomology groups, from which one would get something like
$$ b_{k}(M) \leq \sum\limits_{p+q=k} h^{p,q}(M)$$
as relation between Betti numbers and Dolbeault-Hodge numbers.   So my question is:
Can one show that $d$-exactness implies $\bar\partial$-exactness for a general complex manifold?
I know it can be done for Kähler manifolds using the $\partial\bar\partial$-Lemma, but it seems to be a much stronger argument, since one even gets equality above.

That inequality does hold true, see proposition 4.17 in https://webspace.science.uu.nl/~caval101/homepage/Teaching_files/Cavalcanti-CG2022.pdf

Sorry, I am a bit of confused.. We have a canonical map for $\alpha\in A^{p,q}(X)$ from $H_{dR}^{p+q}(X)$ to $H^{p,q}{\bar\partial}(X)$ by $[\alpha]{d}\mapsto [\alpha]_{\bar\partial}$. So, if you wanna say that "one could see the deRham-cohomology groups as a sub-groups of the Dolbeault cohomology group", shouldn't it be provided that if one has on a general complex manifold, for a $d$-closed $(p,q)$-form $\alpha$, will $\bar\partial$-exactness imply $d$-exactness?

Furthermore, for the inequality you write, it is true for a general manifold, and the equality holds iff the Frolicher spectral sequence degenerates at $E_1$-page. Intuitively, when we only have the "<", this means that  in this case some of the Dolbeault cohomology groups $H^{p,q}_{\bar\partial}(X)$ are “too big” to fit inside the De Rham cohomology $H^{p+q}(X)$.
